# Bound of the form $ \text{tr}\, (AB)^k \le \text{tr} \, f_k(A) + \text{tr} \, f_k(B) $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B$ be Hermitian square matrices, and let $k$ be a positive integer. Does there exist a bound of the form 
  $$ \text{tr}\, (AB)^k \le \text{tr} \, f_k(A) + \text{tr} \, f_k(B) $$
If so, what is $f_k$ (even better, are certain $f_k$ known to give tight bounds)?

For $k=1$, an obvious bound is $f_1(x) = x^2/2$.

For $k=2$, anti-hermiticity of the commutator $\text{tr}\,[A,B]^2 \le 0$ gives $f_2(x) = x^4/2$.

It is tempting to conjecture $f_k = x^{2k}/2$.

Comment: Search for Lieb-Thirring inequality, and apply AM-GM inequality, should give the desired $f_k$.